# How to install pecl-event on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, pecl

I've try to install pecl-event on FreeBSD 8.0, but get error:

```
# pecl install event
Failed to download pecl/event within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.9.1, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/event-0.9.1" to install
install failed
# pecl install "channel://pecl.php.net/event-0.9.1"
downloading event-0.9.1.tar ...
Starting to download event-0.9.1.tar (Unknown size)
.....................done: 113,664 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

What I do wrong? How to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract event-0.9.1.tar file to a temporary folder. (for instance: /tmp/tmp1 )
Go to sub-folder which one includes config.m4 file in temporary folder.

Make sure you have "/usr/local/bin/phpize". If it s not in there... find phpize's location and create symbolic link it to /usr/local/bin/phpize.

Than try to run again